# In Vim, how to autocmd on a specific filename

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim to encrypt a file.

In my .vimrc I have:

```
set viminfo='0,\"0,\/0,:0,f0
setlocal cryptmethod=blowfish
```

AFAIK The first line tells Vim not to save information on .viminfo so the nothing from the file to encrypt is saved.

The problem is that this removes all the viminfo nice features for all the files

I'm searching for something like:

```
autocmd «ThisExactFileNameKeyword» thefileiwanttoencrypt set viminfo='0,\"0,\/0,:0,f0
```

Does Vim provides any command to place on «ThisExactFileNameKeyword»?

**EDIT**
Ingo Karkat's solution works like charm

```
autocmd VimEnter * if ! empty(&l:key) | set viminfo='0,\"0,\/0,:0,f0 | echomsg "Adapted for encrypted editing" | endif
```

I just had to change the encryption method from *blowfish* to *blowfish2* to get rid of a warning on weak method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read `:help 'viminfo'`, you'll notice that this is a **global option**. So, its contents alway apply to the entire Vim session.

In order to differentiate the settings between normal editing and editing of an encrypted file, you have to **use a separate Vim session for editing the encrypted file**.

You can check for this in your `~/.vimrc`, and adapt the `'viminfo'` setting (and others) accordingly. For example:

```
if argc() == 1 && argv(0) ==# 'thefileiwanttoencrypt'
    set viminfo=...
endif
```

or for any encrypted file:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if ! empty(&l:key) | set viminfo=... | echomsg "Adapted for encrypted editing" | endif
```